# Is there a word or phrase for the "log ride face"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a special word or phrase for the act of making an incongruent face or pose, during the final drop in log flume rides?

[image: log ride face]

[Log flumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_flume_%28ride%29) are a very common ride found in many amusement parks, with a long history. Patrons ride in a log boat that travels along a water flume, and the ride culminates in a final, steep drop. A common feature is that just before the drop, a hidden camera takes a photo of the riders, who are usually in a state of shock. The photos are then shown for all to see after the ride, where one may purchase those photos.

This has spawned a practice where some patrons will deliberately make an inappropriate face or pose for this camera, which sometimes produces hilarious results.

Comment: Other than hamming it up for the camera, I don't think so. If ***Jennifer Lawrence's hilarious facial expressions*** dont have a name yet, it's not likely out there.

Comment: So are you looking for the name for the natural reaction or for the hammed up face?

Comment: I hope the creepy looking dude on the far left isn't you.

Answer (score 3):

There is an unofficial term: "**roller coaster face**"

And it is used in this [dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2064365/The-face-fear-The-roller-coaster-faces-thrill-seekers-want-forget.html) article:

> The face of fear: The **rollercoaster faces** that these thrill seekers will want to forget

Also, There is a feeling called [air-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-time) that may cause this:

> Air time is the feeling of weightlessness or negative gravity force experienced on a roller coaster or other amusement rides.
>
> Air-time is caused by inertia of the train and the riders. As the train goes over a hill, the mass of the riders tends to resist the downward motion of the ride vehicle, resulting in riders being briefly lifted out of their seats.

Perhaps we could call it "**air-time face**" then.

---

There is also **wobble face**:

[image]
<sup>*~Source: http://www.designboom.com/art/jowls-flap-and-fur-flies-for-shake-dog-photos-by-carli-davidson-10-23-2013/*</sup>

Video also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OEMOsMxYGk

Comment: ‘Roller coaster face’ is exactly right. Assuming, of course, that the asker isn’t asking for an expression that only goes for water log rides specifically, to the exclusion of roller coasters.

Comment: @Janus: If that is the case, OP already have the answer in the question: log ride face :)  Though I see that it is  never used in online sources so we can assume that "roller coaster face" is a hypernym for all faces of similar rides.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say 'mugging for the camera'. It's a very British English usage of the word, coming from 'mug' as a slang noun synonymous with 'face', so 'to mug' is 'to make a face', as a deliberate action for the camera.

Answer (score 1):

I think if the face were natural it could be referred to as the **oh shit face**.  Not sure about common usage but used amongst people I know.

"When she saw her cell phone dropping into the pool she made her oh shit face."